# pyspark pandas UDF EOFError on macOS

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Running pandas UDF on macOS (Big Sur) result in the error below, while the exact same code works perfectly fine on Google Colab. Moreover, spark UDFs work fine.

```
20/12/09 14:02:22 ERROR ArrowPythonRunner: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 585, in main
    eval_type = read_int(infile)
  File "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 595, in read_int
    raise EOFError
EOFError

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:503)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:489)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:729)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:132)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.directBuffer(PlatformDependent.java:490)
    at io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:243)
    at io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.nioBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:233)
    at io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.nioBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:245)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.ArrowRecordBatch.computeBodyLength(ArrowRecordBatch.java:222)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.serialize(MessageSerializer.java:240)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowWriter.writeRecordBatch(ArrowWriter.java:132)
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowWriter.writeBatch(ArrowWriter.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:94)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.writeIteratorToStream(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(PythonRunner.scala:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1932)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRunner.scala:218)
```

**Code**

The code is a minimal example based on the [code accompanying](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/1281142885375883/2174302049319883/7729323681064935/latest.html) the [introductory blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html).

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rand, count
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, pandas_udf, PandasUDFType


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

# Print spark version
print(pyspark.__version__)

# Create example dataframe
df = spark.range(0, 10 * 1000 * 1000).withColumn('id', (col('id') / 10000).cast('integer')).withColumn('v', rand())
df.cache()
df.count()

df.show()


@udf('double')
def plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

# using Spark UDF works fine
df.withColumn('v', plus_one(df.v)).agg(count(col('v'))).show()


@pandas_udf("double", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_plus_one(v):
    return v + 1

# using Pandas UDF results in EofError
df.withColumn('v', pandas_plus_one(df.v)).agg(count(col('v'))).show()


@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def pandas_subtract_mean(pdf):
    return pdf.assign(v=pdf.v - pdf.v.mean())

df.groupby('id').apply(pandas_subtract_mean).agg(count(col('v'))).show()
```

Additional code to setup pyspark on colab:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget https://apache.osuosl.org/spark/spark-3.0.1/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2"
```

**Local environment**

```
findspark==1.4.2
numpy==1.18.5
pandas==1.1.4
pyarrow==2.0.0
pyspark==3.0.1
```

- Python: 3.8.5
- Platform': macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.9

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Java 11. For future reference: downgrading to Java 8 resolved the issue.